# HWIOAuthBundle error while sending http request

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I use

```
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.8",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0"
```

and for first time try enter to social network I have error:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Exception\HttpTransportException: "Error while sending HTTP request" at /home/myproject/vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/OAuth/ResourceOwner/AbstractResourceOwner.php line 257
```

but when try return back and try again- everything ok,
problem identification for both provider,

I add to config `verify_peer: false` but still have error for first enter
my config:

```
hwi_oauth:
    http_client:
        verify_peer: false
    connect:
        account_connector: optima_oauth_provider
    firewall_names: [main]
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           "%facebook_app_id%"
            client_secret:       "%facebook_app_secret%"
            scope:               "email"
            options:
                display: popup
            infos_url:     "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,link,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.type(square)"
            paths:
                email:          email
                profilepicture: picture.data.url
        google:
            type:                google
            client_id:           "%google_app_id%"
            client_secret:       "%google_app_secret%"
            scope:               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Download `cacert.pem` from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html, put in any location and edit your `php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo = "/any/location/cacert.pem"
```

Then restart your web-server.

Answer (score 0):

In  my cas i was running the app on a docker container; after debugging actually, it was a curl issue

```
curl -v https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token
```

when running I found `could not resole host  graph.facebook.com`

fixed by mapping 443:443 ports on my docker machine